# textFieldShouldEndEditing doesn't get called when using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my ViewController, I got `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but this never gets called. I searched why this wasn't get called and I found that I use this:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

to dismiss the keyboard when the background is tapped. Any idea how I can fix this, that both the dismisskeyboard tap on background and the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` work?

Comment: What is your requirement actually ?

Answer (score 0):

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never gets called because you might not be implementing the `UITableViewDelegate`.

you should just use this with your control to resign from responder

```
 [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I did implement this. Its the TapGestureRecognizer that causes problems, when I delete that part it works.

Comment: if you have textField in your viewContoller , when you tap then inside the method just `resignFirstResponder`from your textField

Comment: I resignFirstResponder in the "dismisskeyboard" method

Answer (score 0):

try like this it'l helps you,

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if(![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){

//resign your textfield here
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever I set the UITapGestureRecognizer, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];

[tbl addGestureRecognizer:tap];

-(void)dismissKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:tbl];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tbl indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil)
        NSLog(@"Resign");
    else
        NSLog(@"Did select Row, %i",indexPath.row);// Do your stuff as you are doing in didSelectRow
}
```

**Implement this**

Comment: does this method calling ?

Comment: It does get called, the problem is that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called

Comment: remove that tap gesture and place this. just see my edited answer'

Comment: I did that but if I click the background, the keyboard doesn't dismiss

Answer (score 0):

If you tap on this view. You have to override you delegate method `shouldReceiveTouch` to return `NO`. If touch happened on `tableView`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.tblView]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Now two delegate methods will fire.. `Note:` self.tblView is a tableView

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
return TRUE;
```

Ok see how you get on with that one.... then if it works read up on the documentation for a thorough explanation so you get a clear understanding.